# Tool for Importing a mysql database with where condition

Tags: phpmyadmin, export, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am searching for a tool/software/web application which i can use to import mysql database using where condition, i am using phpmyadmin, but there is no option for importing with where condition. Actually i want to import a database with where condition in which i will give some value for a particular column and i will import only selected columns.

In phpmyadmin i can import a database easily but cannot use where condition in it. if is possible to export some columns in phpmyadmin please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am excited to see if any tool having these kind of feature

Comment: hope this would help you: https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Migration_Toolkit_-_From_table-SQLWhere_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm

Comment: And this: https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Migration_Toolkit_-_From_table-Transform_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm

Comment: STOP spamming here.....,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself, its rather easy then thought can just require familarity with phpmyadmin
i hope this will help someone else

step 1- (follow only if you are able to run and execute query in phpmyadmin), click sql tab in 
           php myadmin

step2-  run your query witch selected columns,

step3- if you are able to run the query correctly with your desired fields, at the end of the page you will see export button, hit the export button

step4 - now you have customization for your export, i recommend you using update feature insted of insert, chek the (save file as) option and name your file. and hit export. (if this seems clumsy and if you feel hard to do, tell me)

NOte:- if  you are cannot follow any step, please tell me